# Find root of a function in a given interval

Tags: python, function, numpy, scipy

I am trying to find the root of a function between by `[0, pi/2]`, all algorithms in scipy have this condition : `f(a)` and `f(b)` must have opposite signs.
In my case `f(0)*f(pi/2) > 0` is there any solution, I precise I don't need solution outside [`0, pi/2]`.

The function:

```
def dG(thetaf,psi,gamma) :
   return 0.35*((cos(psi))**2)*(2*sin(3*thetaf/2+2*gamma)+(1+4*sin(gamma)**2)*sin(thetaf/2)-‌​sin(3*thetaf/2))+(sin(psi)**2)*sin(thetaf/2)
```

Comment: "is there any solution" - depends on `f` surely...

Comment: This is how these algorithms function. If you don't have opposite signs, you either have zero roots, or more than 1 root. In the latter case, which root do you expect the algorithm to return?

Comment: @MrE `def dG(thetaf,psi,gamma) : 
    return 0.35*((cos(psi))**2)*(2*sin(3*thetaf/2+2*gamma)+(1+4*sin(gamma)**2)*sin(thetaf/2)-sin(3*thetaf/2))+(sin(psi)**2)*sin(thetaf/2)`
I am trying to find the root of this function where `thetaf` is my variable and psi gamma are in `[0, pi/2]`

Comment: @MrE in `[0,pi/2]` i have roots, i ploted my function for some value of gamma and psi, and i see that  there is a solution of my problem

Comment: If `psi` and `gamma` are within `[0, pi/2]` but you're using `thetaf` as your independent variable, you're misunderstanding something: it's `thetaf` that needs to be in `[0, pi/2]`.

Comment: @MrE 
Here is my algo :
`for i, gamma in enumerate(gammas):`
    `for j, psi in enumerate(psis):`
        `g = lambda thetaf: dG(thetaf,psi,gamma)`
         `x[i,j] = optimize.brenth(g,0,pi/2,maxiter=1000)`

Comment: I plotted your function with `gamma=0.5, psi=0.5` and with `thetaf` running from `0` to `pi/2` and it doesn't change sign. i.e. there is not always a root

Comment: @MrE
Take psi = 0 and any value for gamma

Comment: @Abdallah doesn't seem to be the case. [Here](http://pastebin.ca/2608367) is my code to demonstrate. Maybe you really want to solve a different problem (e.g. restricting to where you have a root)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and on @Mike Graham's answer, you can do something that will check where  the change of signs are. Given `y = dG(x, psi, gamma)`:

```
x[y[:-1]*y[1:] < 0]
```

will return the positions where you had a change of sign. You can an iterative process to find the roots numerically up to the error tolerance that you need:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, cos

def find_roots(f, a, b, args=[], errTOL=1e-6):
    err = 1.e6
    x = np.linspace(a, b, 100)
    while True:
        y = f(x, *args)
        pos = y[:-1]*y[1:] < 0
        if not np.any(pos):
            print('No roots in this interval')
            return roots
        err = np.abs(y[pos]).max()
        if err <= errTOL:
            roots = 0.5*x[:-1][pos] + 0.5*x[1:][pos]
            return roots
        inf_sup = zip(x[:-1][pos], x[1:][pos])
        x = np.hstack([np.linspace(inf, sup, 10) for inf, sup in inf_sup])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a root only if, between `a` and `b`, there are values with different signs. If this happens there are almost certainly going to be multiple roots. Which one of those do you want to find?

You're going to have to take what you know about `f` to figure out how to deal with this. If you know there is exactly one root, you can just find the local minimumn. If you know there are two, you can find the minimum and use that's coordinate `c` to find one of the two roots (one between `a` and `c`, the other between `c` and what used to be called `b`).

You need to know what you're looking for to be able to find it.