# Find a root of a function in a given range

Tags: python, function, numpy, scipy

I have a set of functions `f_t` with several roots (two actually). I want to find the "first" root and doing this with `fsolve` works fine most of the time. The problem is, that the two roots converge, as t goes to infinity. (a simple exmple of my functions would be `f_t(x) = x^2 - 1/t`). So the larger `t` gets, the more mistakes `fsolve` makes. Is there a **predefined** function, similar to `fsolve` to which I can tell it should only look in a given range (e.g. find always the root in `[0, inf`)).

The question is essentially the same as https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91784/how-to-find-numerically-all-roots-of-a-function-in-a-given-range?noredirect=1&lq=1, however the answers there are for Mathematica, I want them in Python.

PS: I now how I can write my own algorithm, but as these tend to be slower as builtins I was hoping to find a builtin that does the same. Especially I've read this post [Find root of a function in a given interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484796/find-root-of-a-function-in-a-given-interval)

Comment: [Tried this?](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/optimize.html#root-finding)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is generally accepted that for smooth, well-behaved functions, the [Brent method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrentsMethod.html) is the fastest method guaranteed to give a root.  As with the other two methods listed, you must provide an interval [a,b] across which the function is continuous and changes sign.

The Scipy implementation is documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html).  An example use case for the function you mentioned could look like this:

```
from __future__ import division
import scipy

def func(x,t):
    return(x**2 - 1/t)

t0 = 1
min = 0
max = 100000 # set max to some sufficiently large value

root = scipy.optimize.brentq(func, min, max, args = (t0)) # args just supplies any extra
                                                       # argument for the function that isn't the varied parameter
```

Comment: Just cosmetics but you might want to define `t`, for Python2 it might also be better to use `1./t`. +1, nice solution as well.

Comment: good call, thanks.

I was debating whether or not to worry about division in this little bit of code.  I just ended up doing the lazy thing with a `from __future__`.

Comment: Any idea whether one can use that to find all roots in a given range as in my answer below? I was surprised not to find that in standard scipy.

Comment: I think that's the downside.  I'm not aware of any way to get multiple roots within the function itself.  I wonder how slow it would be to just use the found root as the new `min` value and sort of iterate through the possible zeros

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`scipy.optimize.bisect`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.bisect.html#scipy.optimize.bisect), which takes two parameters `a` and `b` that define the starting interval. There are a few limitations, though:

- The interval needs to be finite. You cannot search in [0, inf].
- The function must flip sign at the root (`f(a)` and `f(b)` must have opposite signs) so, for example, you cannot find the root of `f(x) = abs(x)` (If that is even a "root" in the mathematical sense). Also, it won't work for `f(x) = x**2 - 1` and an interval of [a, b] with a<-1 and b>1.
- The method is not gradient based. This can be an advantage if the function is very jagged or expensive to evaluate but it may be slower on other functions.

An alternative is to use [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) to minimize `abs(f(x))`. This function can take `bounds` that include infinity. But minimization may end up in a non-root local minimum of the function.

Comment: Dealing with infinity is indeed an issue, also in my answer below based on `chebpy`. But I guess for practical purposes one can just plug in a huge number.

Comment: @Cleb that's right, but a huge numberwill increase the number of bisection steps. One step per double range.

Answer (score 2):

Classically, you could use [`root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root

def func(x, t):
    return x ** 2 - 1. / t

t = 5000

res = root(func, 0.5, args=(t, )).x[0]
print res
```

That would print the positive one, in this case `0.0141421356237`.

If you want to **specify the range and determine all roots within this interval**, you can use [`chebpy`](https://github.com/chebpy/chebpy):

```
from chebpy import chebfun

x = chebfun('x', [-100000, 100000])
t = 5000
f = x ** 2 - 1. / t

rts = f.roots()
print rts
```

This would print both the positive and the negative root, in this case

```
[-0.01413648  0.01413648]
```

If you only want to look in the positive range, you can change

```
x = chebfun('x', [-100000, 100000])
```

to

```
x = chebfun('x', [0, 100000])
```

I am, however, not sure how to use infinity, but you can just use a very high number for practical purposes, I think.