# rewriting fsolve function from maple to python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, maple

I am trying to solve the equation numerically using `fsolve` on interval 0,100 with maximum solutions `n`. I did it in Maple and it does what I exactly need. 
Here is my code:

```
E:= proc (a, n, maxe) local E1, E2; E1 := fsolve(tan((1/2)*w*a) == 
tanh((1/2)*w*a), w, 0 .. maxe, maxsols = n); E2 := {-E1[2 .. -1]} union {E1} 
end proc:
aa:=1.5; nn:=4: sqrtener(aa,nn,100);
```

My output:

```
{-20.42035224, -14.13716549, -7.853204624, 0., 7.853204624, 14.13716549, 20.42035224}
```

But I have to rewrite it in Python language. So used the same function:

```
def E(a, n, maxe):
    E1 = fsolve(lambda w : np.tan(w * a / 2) - np.tanh(w * a / 2),range(maxe), maxfev = n)
    E2 = set(np.array(E1)) | set(np.array((-1)*E1[:-1]-1))
    return(E2)
print(E(1.5,4,100))
```

But it returns me 200 numbers from -100 to 100 even if I put the parameter `maxfev = 4`

May be someone know another function instead of fsolve?

Comment: Where does fsolve come from? Have you looked at the differences in behavrior between Maple's and xxx's?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, yes i did. I just do not know how to write it in Python to have the same result as in Maple

Comment: You might be interested in [`solveset`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html). Not sure if `fsolve` can handle this but I don't think so.

Comment: You could also try [`chebfun`](https://github.com/chebpy/chebpy). Check [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271440/find-a-root-of-a-function-in-a-given-range/43275992#43275992).

Comment: It is not clear to me what the Maple code is doing, because `a = 1.5` and `w = 7.853204624` is not a solution to the equation `tan(a*w/2) - tanh(a*w/2) = 0`.  With `a = 1.5`, I get the seven solutions closest to 0  to be `[-17.80235837, -13.61356816,  -9.42477699,  -5.23546975,
         0.        ,   5.23546975,   9.42477699,  13.61356816,
        17.80235837]`

Comment: OK, apparently the Maple code is displaying `a*w`, not `w`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes, th function tan(a*w/2) - tanh(a*w/2) = 0 should give me closet solutions to 0.  I could write another way in python  : `fsolve(lambda w : np.tan(w * a / 2) - np.tanh(w * a / 2),n) ` and then make`for n in np.arange(-4,4): print(E(a,n)`. But as for me it is a bit weird to write like this.